# Disable Nginx checking pages exist

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an Angular 9 application that works fine with `ng serve`, but when I build it and run under `nginx` if the user presses F5 refresh on any page I get a `404` not found page from `nginx`. This happens because the Angular route is not a valid URL page.

How to tell nginx **NOT** to check that the page exists, and let Angular handle the routing?

I tried with [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists) with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must configure the server to return `index.html` for unknown locations.

The [angular docs: Fallback configuration examples](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples) also includes an example for nginx:

> Nginx: use try_files, as described in Front Controller Pattern Web Apps, modified to serve index.html:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```